# Flutter GoRouter preserve state of route outside of main navigation

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-go-router

I recently started using GoRouter for navigation in my app.
I have already created a main menu with a BottomBar and two more routes, one for the login and one for the chat.

Here is my code so far:

```
GoRouter appRouter = GoRouter(
  navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
  debugLogDiagnostics: true,
  initialLocation: '/feed',
  redirect: (context, state) {
    final authState = context.read<AuthBloc>().state;

    final bool loggedIn = authState.status == AuthStatus.authenticated;
    final bool onLoginPage = state.path == '/login';

    if (authState.status == AuthStatus.initial) return null;

    if (loggedIn && state.fullPath == '/login') {
      return '/feed';
    }

    if (!loggedIn && !onLoginPage) {
      return '/login';
    }

    return null;
  },
  routes: [
    StatefulShellRoute.indexedStack(
      pageBuilder: (context, state, navigationShell) {
        return MaterialPage(
            key: state.pageKey,
            child: Homepage(navigationShell: navigationShell));
      },
      branches: [
        StatefulShellBranch(
          navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorFeedKey,
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              name: 'feed',
              path: '/feed',
              pageBuilder: (context, state) =>
                  const NoTransitionPage(child: FeedPage()),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        StatefulShellBranch(
          navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorVideoKey,
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              name: 'video',
              path: '/video',
              pageBuilder: (context, state) =>
                  const NoTransitionPage(child: VideoPage()),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        StatefulShellBranch(
          navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorUploadKey,
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              name: 'upload',
              path: '/upload',
              pageBuilder: (context, state) =>
                  const NoTransitionPage(child: UploadPostPage()),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        StatefulShellBranch(
          navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorSearchKey,
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
              name: 'search',
              path: '/search',
              pageBuilder: (context, state) =>
                  const NoTransitionPage(child: MapSample()),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        StatefulShellBranch(
          navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorProfileKey,
          routes: [
            GoRoute(
                name: 'profile',
                path: '/profile',
                pageBuilder: (context, state) =>
                    const NoTransitionPage(child: ProfilePage()),
                routes: [
                  GoRoute(
                      name: 'profileOther',
                      path: ':uid',
                      pageBuilder: (context, state) {
                        final uid = state.pathParameters['uid'];
                        return NoTransitionPage(child: ProfilePage(uid: uid));
                      }),
                ]),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
    GoRoute(
      name: 'login',
      path: '/login',
      builder: (context, state) => const LoginPage(),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
      name: 'chat',
      path: '/chat',
      builder: (context, state) => StreamChat(
        client: context.read<StreamChatClient>(),
        streamChatThemeData: StreamChatThemeData.dark().copyWith(
          ownMessageTheme: StreamMessageThemeData(
            messageBackgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
            messageTextStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
        child: const ChatPage(),
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

Now to my problem:
I don't want to reopen the chat page and load the state every time. The ChatPage should be opened once and then you should always be able to open this page without it being completely reloaded.

Currently I use `context.goNamed('chat');`, but here the BackButton is missing which brings me back to the main navigation.

If I use `context.pushNamed('chat')` I have a BackButton but the page gets newly loaded every time i push the route.

Is there a way that I can keep the state of the ChatPage and not always have to push the page to the NavigationStack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way is to put your chat page inside the `StatefulShellRoute` as one of its branches. Then it will be preserving it's state. If you use BottomNavigationBar or some other common UI elements in `StatefulShellRoute`, you can hide these elements for your chat page (just check, if current route is `ChatPage` route.